# How to connect to host using Remote SSH without automatically installing VSCode server?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access

I am using system-on-module running a [Toradex Embedded Linux BSP 2.8](https://developer.toradex.com/software/linux/linux-software#2-bsp-28) and I'm trying to enable remote debugging Python apps. For this I'm using VSCode with Remote SSH extension. The problem is that it  it tries and fails to install VSCode Server on the host. This is the output from VSCode:

```
[20:19:37.760] Log Level: 2
[20:19:37.766] remote-ssh-nightly@2020.11.38340
[20:19:37.767] win32 x64
[20:19:37.770] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+192.168.1.123", attempt 1
[20:19:37.771] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[20:19:37.772] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[20:19:37.772] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {}
[20:19:37.772] "remote.SSH.sshPath": undefined
[20:19:37.773] "remote.SSH.sshConfigurationFile": undefined
[20:19:37.773] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[20:19:37.773] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[20:19:37.775] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[20:19:37.776] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[20:19:37.776] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[20:19:37.776] "remote.SSH.maxReconnectionAttempts": 9007199254740991
[20:19:37.779] SSH Resolver called for host: 192.168.1.123
[20:19:37.779] Setting up SSH remote "192.168.1.123"
[20:19:37.843] Using commit id "e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f" and quality "stable" for server
[20:19:37.857] Install and start server if needed
[20:19:43.883] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[20:19:43.974] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5

[20:19:43.987] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 61045 192.168.1.123 bash
[20:19:43.991] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[20:19:44.570] > d00250925a8b: running
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[20:19:44.570] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[20:19:44.673] > Acquiring lock on /home/root/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789
> 406efe8f/vscode-remote-lock.root.e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f       
[20:19:44.712] > Installing to /home/root/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406e
> fe8f...
> main: line 52: 1607624384%N/1000000: division by 0 (error token is "N/1000000") 
> d00250925a8b%%1%%
[20:19:44.730] > Downloading with wget
[20:19:54.206] > Download complete
[20:19:54.231] > main: line 52: 1607624394%N/1000000: division by 0 (error token is "N/1000000")
> main: line 60: - : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "- ")        
[20:19:54.236] > main: line 52: 1607624394%N/1000000: division by 0 (error token is "N/1000000")
> d00250925a8b%%2%%
> tar --version:
> tar: unrecognized option '--version'
[20:19:54.253] > BusyBox v1.24.1 (2020-06-10 16:36:39 UTC) multi-call binary.
> 
> Usage: tar -[cxtZzJjahmvO] [-X FILE] [-T FILE] [-f TARFILE] [-C DIR] [FILE]...
[20:20:00.456] > main: line 52: 1607624400%N/1000000: division by 0 (error token is "N/1000000")
> main: line 60: - : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "- ")
> ERROR: tar exited with non-0 exit code: 0
> Trigger local server download
> d00250925a8b:trigger_server_download
> platform==linux==
> vscodeArch==armhf==
> destFolder==/home/root/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe
> 8f==
> d00250925a8b:trigger_server_download_end
> Waiting for client to transfer server archive...
[20:20:00.457] Got request to download on client for {"platform":"linux","arch":"armhf","destFolder":"/home/root/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f"}
[20:20:00.458] Downloading VS Code server locally...
[20:20:00.463] > 
> Waiting for /home/root/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe
> 8f/vscode-scp-done.flag and vscode-server.tar.gz to exist
[20:20:00.481] > 
> 
[20:20:09.513] Downloaded VS Code server to c:\Users\Cristi\AppData\Local\Temp\11e04d86-6ef3-4156-b828-f18fc94d5574
[20:20:09.517] Renamed VS Code server to c:\Users\Cristi\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode_server_1607624409513\vscode-server.tar.gz
[20:20:09.521] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[20:20:09.606] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5

[20:20:09.619] Testing scp with "scp"
[20:20:09.766] scp exited with code: 1
[20:20:09.767] Got stderr from scp: usage: scp [-346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] source ... target
[20:20:09.768] Copying file to remote with scp vscode-server.tar.gz vscode-scp-done.flag 192.168.1.123:/home/root/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f
[20:20:09.768] Using cwd: file:///c%3A/Users/Cristi/AppData/Local/Temp/vscode_server_1607624409513
[20:20:09.768] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[20:20:10.350] > vscode-server.tar.gz                            0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[20:20:11.364] > vscode-server.tar.gz                           47%   12MB  12.3MB/s   00:01 ETA
[20:20:12.373] > vscode-server.tar.gz                           90%   24MB  12.2MB/s   00:00 ETA
[20:20:12.761] > vscode-server.tar.gz                          100%   26MB  10.9MB/s   00:02    
[20:20:12.780] > 
> vscode-scp-done.flag                          100%    9     4.4KB/s   00:00    
[20:20:13.090] "Copy server to host" terminal command done
[20:20:15.484] > Found flag and server on host
[20:20:15.501] > main: line 52: 1607624415%N/1000000: division by 0 (error token is "N/1000000")
> d00250925a8b%%2%%
> tar --version:
> tar: unrecognized option '--version'
[20:20:15.507] > 
> BusyBox v1.24.1 (2020-06-10 16:36:39 UTC) multi-call binary.
> 
> Usage: tar -[cxtZzJjahmvO] [-X FILE] [-T FILE] [-f TARFILE] [-C DIR] [FILE]...  
[20:20:15.514] > 
[20:20:21.739] > main: line 52: 1607624421%N/1000000: division by 0 (error token is "N/1000000")
> ERROR: tar exited with non-0 exit code: 0
> Already attempted local download, failing
> d00250925a8b: start
> exitCode==37==
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId==angstrom==
[20:20:21.747] > 
> arch==armv7l==
> tmpDir==/run/user/0==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult==error==
> didLocalDownload==1==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime====
> d00250925a8b: end
[20:20:21.749] Received install output: 
exitCode==37==
listeningOn====
osReleaseId==angstrom==
arch==armv7l==
tmpDir==/run/user/0==
platform==linux==
unpackResult==error==
didLocalDownload==1==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime====

[20:20:21.763] Resolver error: Error: Failed to install the VS Code Server
    at Function.ServerInstallError (c:\Users\Cristi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-nightly-2020.11.38340\out\extension.js:1:95433)
    at c:\Users\Cristi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-nightly-2020.11.38340\out\extension.js:1:93971
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\Cristi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-nightly-2020.11.38340\out\extension.js:1:94151)
    at I (c:\Users\Cristi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-nightly-2020.11.38340\out\extension.js:127:107038)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async c:\Users\Cristi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-nightly-2020.11.38340\out\extension.js:127:104953
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\Cristi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-nightly-2020.11.38340\out\extension.js:127:110290)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\Cristi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-nightly-2020.11.38340\out\extension.js:127:108354)
    at async c:\Users\Cristi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-nightly-2020.11.38340\out\extension.js:127:129588
[20:20:21.766] > 
> main: line 60: - : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "- ")
[20:20:21.766] > 
[20:20:21.769] ------




[20:20:22.736] "install" terminal command done
[20:20:22.736] Install terminal quit with output: main: line 60: - : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "- ")
```

I've tried unpacking the tar.gz file and manually executing the server.sh file. It shows that the server is listening on port 8000:

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.123
Extension host agent listening on 8000


[17:54:03] Extension host agent started.
```

But when I connect with Remote SSH, it retries to install VSCode server, although it is running.

What do you suggest I should do to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

I began having the same issue yesterday after rebooting my system running vscode.

I tried rolling back the Remote-SSH extension to the previous three versions with no change. **Extensions > Right click on 'Remote - SSH' > 'Install Another Version...'**

I found [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4182) on the vscode-remote github with different errors, but the same symptom of updating to vscode 1.52.0 and Remote-SSH 0.62.0. The solution there was to downgrade to [vscode 1.51.1](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.51.1/win32-x64-user/stable) and Remote-SSH 0.61.0

Remote-SSH 0.61.0 didn't work for me, but 0.56.0 did.

Comment: the same issue, switch to 0.56 works for me.

Answer (score 1):

My VS Code just updated itself to November 2020 and the Remote SSH extension, and now I get this error too. My target system, like yours, is BusyBox based (maybe this has something to do with it).
I'm using this setup for a year or so. This isn't normal behavior.

EDIT: This trick worked in the meanwhile. My home folder is shared between BusyBox target systems and a main glibc PC. By doing SSH to the glibc PC, installing VS Code server worked. From then on, I could SSH to my busybox targets and have the updated VS Code server.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can you detail the configuration steps so I can try your suggestion?